# inserting a row in Oracle sql using command prompt and by using Apex,but only one row is getting inserted

Tags: sql

When I insert a row in command prompt and access it, it is successfully done. But when I see it in `Apex` it doesn't show any data in table. What is the mistake. And one more thing. When I insert a row by using apex it shows in command prompt also but it doesn't give the result in my `JDBC` program, it gives only one row.

Comment: You should clarify your question and phrase it in a way that identifies exactly what issue your having and what have you have done to try and resolve it.

Comment: Did you `commit` after inserting?

Comment: Thanks Utsav...i got it